# Notification, extras передать из Service

Tags: java, android

Ребят, сдаюсь! Подскажите плз, курю интернет несколько дней, перепробовал все описанное, не работает. Задача: при нажатии на уведомление мне нужно открыть нужный фрагмент. Чтобы открыть нужный фрагмент, нужно из сервиса передать имя нужного фрагмента. Не получается передать параметры extras в Activity, они всегда приходят null.

Вырезка кода из службы:

```
public class ServiceFirebaseCloudMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService
{

    @Override 
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) { 
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityListMeetingsTb.class);
        intent.putExtra("fragmentName", "fragmentListChats");
        intent.putExtra("1", "1");

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("fragmentName", "fragmentListChats");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ActivityListMeetingsTb.class); 
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent); 

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "RendChat")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_outline_message_24) 
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()) 
                .setAutoCancel(true) 
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Вырезка из манифеста:

```
        <activity android:name=".ActivityListMeetingsTb" android:launchMode="singleTask">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="Open_ActivityListMeetingsTb" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Ловлю параметры в Activity:

```
    @Override 
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        String str = intent.getStringExtra("fragmentName");
        String str2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("1");


        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intent.getExtras().get("fragmentName") != null) {
            String str3 = intent.getStringExtra("fragmentName");
            String str4 = getIntent().getStringExtra("fragmentName");
        }


    }
```

Вырезка из кода при отправке уведомления, передаю click_action:

```
                json.put("to", partnerInfo.getToken());

                JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
                info.put("title", "Сообщение");   // Notification title
                info.put("body", "У вас есть новое сообщение"); // Notification body
                info.put("click_action", "Open_ActivityListMeetingsTb");

                json.put("notification", info);
```

Все вроде по книге проделываю, нужного результата нет. Вычитал альтернативный способ, использовать компонент Navigation, ну пока не знаю что это и стоит ли вникать в него.
Ребят, мозговой штурм, любые наводки, любые мысли, излагайте, плз.

Comment: У вас в вопросе есть лишний, неиспользуемый код - удалите его, он мешает восприятию - что вы реально используете. Например `stackBuilder `, вроде, не используется. Также не ясно вызывается ли ваш код вообще. У вас, наверное FCM используется, хотя вы об этом не упоминаете. И, наверное, с `notification` в теле. В этом случае код ваш в `onMessageReceived ` не будет вызываться в определённых условиях (в фоне/не в фоне, не помню точно, надо доку смотреть). Также, вы в `onNewIntent` часть данных из нового интента берёте, а часть из старого, где их тоже нет.

Comment: Ну и ещё можно попробовать `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Comment: Попробуйте поменять `getApplicationContext()`, на `this` -  `Service` сам по себе уже есть контекст

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в зависимости от android:launchMode мой код получения extras вызывается или в onNewIntent или onCreate. Часть строк я беру из нового или из старого, да, я это понимаю и для эксперимента пробую и так и так, не работает. Отправляю уведомления с девайса на девайс через "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send". android:launchMode="singleInstance" попробовал, не помогло.

Comment: @Barmaley пробовал, не помогает. Оставил getApplicationContext() в большинстве народ юзает его.

Comment: @Pitry, а код у вас точно вызывается? Вы проверяли это? Покажите в вопросе что именно вы отсылаете на `fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` - мне кажется вы путаете и смешиваете 2 разных способа открытия экрана по пушу - проще всего не использовать `notification` поле - так у вас будет полный программный контроль над происходящим.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил вырезку из формирования уведомления. Я отладчиком встаю на строки, где получаю extras, отладка останавливается на точке останова, строки всегда вызываются и всегда null.

Comment: @Pitry, попробуйте заменить `json.put("notification", info);` на `json.put("data", info);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Попробовал, не помогло. Я думаю дело не в этом. Уведомления я получаю и извлекаю из них данные в Service, а вот передать в Activity дальше, ни через putExtra, ни через Bundle не получается. Перепроверял как у других, менял последовательность и прочее. Может есть другой способ передавать параметры?

Comment: @Pitry, другие способы есть. Но через Intent - правильный способ. Скорее всего вы пробуете как-то не так. У меня способ передачи через Intent прекрасно работает. Проверять самому долго, но я бы такую задачу решал бы так: 1. В пуше только `data`. 2. У активити - `singleInstance` 3. В `onCreate` и `onNewIntent()` - вызов метода проверки интента на наличие данных в нём. 4. В интент складирование данных через Bundle, не через `putExtra` На 95% уверен, что это бы сработало с первого же раза.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не работает. Ребят, есть еще идеи?

Comment: Должно работать. Покажите целиком код в виде репозитория на GitHub например. Возможно, кто-то сумеет найти время чтобы покопаться. Но тут, конечно, понадобится ключ для отправки пушей. Дополнительный можно создать в консоли Firebase и потом удалить

Comment: Вопрос так и не решен, выберу время, переделаю посылку на json.put("data", info); вынесу в отдельное приложение и буду пробовать.